# Why there is no window show after I run the camera_calibration node?

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I run the node "camera_calibration" like this:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/pgr_camera/image_raw camera:=/pgr_camera
```

it shows as below:

```
Waiting for service /pgr_camera/set_camera_info ... 

OK 

*** Added sample 1, p_x = 0.897, p_y = 0.349, p_size = 0.277, skew = 0.027

Segmentation fault
```

Is there any one who can tell me why?

I am using electric on Ubuntu 10.04.And when I run the node "camera_calibration",there is no checkerboard in front of the camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51072/why-there-is-no-window-show-after-i-run-the-camera_calibration-node?/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-26**:
What device and camera driver are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The resolution ratio is too large.
The node worked after I reduced the resolution ratio.Maybe too much data result in the Segmentation fault.

---

Originally posted by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) with karma: 49 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-14**:
Just for the sake of completeness, could you add the resolution that used to SEGFAULT and the resolution that doesn't?

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-06**:
1280*960 lead to SEGFAULT ,and 640*480 doesn't.